# Select distinct rows and apply a filter

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Could someone help me with this table?

```
col1    col2
0       1
0       1
1       0
1       1
2       0
2       1
3       1
3       1
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d076)

I'd like to select distinct values from the first column and filter out the values that have zeroes in the second column. The result should be the following list: [0, 3]

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY. This is a problem for relational tables.

Comment: I simplified the table structure for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct col1 from test where 
    col1 not in (select col1 from test where col2 = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I gave you the "Accepted answer" because you were the fastest :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `col1`
FROM `test`
WHERE `col1` NOT IN (
  SELECT `col1`
  FROM `test`
  WHERE `col2` = 0)
```

Or using a `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.`col1`
FROM `test` a
LEFT JOIN `test` b ON a.`col1` = b.`col1` AND b.`col2` = 0
WHERE b.`col1` IS NULL
```

[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d076/20)

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1
from tab
group by col1
having count(case when col2 = 0 then col2 end) = 0 -- only those where no zero exists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1
from test
group by col1
having min(col2) <> 0
```

Test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d076/26/0

If col2 has values below 0 you can use:

```
select col1
from test
group by col1
having group_concat(col2) not like '%,0%'
   and group_concat(col2) not like '%0,%'
   and group_concat(col2) <> '0'
```

Comment: What about **col2=-1**? You might have to add **and max(col2) <> 0**

Comment: His data shows all 0s and 1s in that column. Yes it does rely on that actually being representative of the data in his table. However if that data is representative of the data in his table, this has a cleaner execution plan than the answer he selected as it does not use a subquery.